# How to get card type information using unimag credit card reader

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-4.0.1, credit-card-track-data

I want to integrate card swipe feature in my application using unimag card reader device provided by ID Tech. It provides name, account number and expiry date in a single string. But no information about the card type. Is there a way to retrieve the information about the "The type of Card" user hols. Like visa, master, etc.

Comment: More of a localised hardware question than a programming question.

Comment: hey can you please guide me about implementing Card Swipe Feature in ios i am in big trouble while using  unimag card reader device provided by ID Tech.

Answer (score 1):

Card type is determine from first couple of digits

example code here
http://cuinl.tripod.com/Tips/o-1.htm

a quick google for implementations :-)

Answer (score 0):

The cliff notes version:

If card starts with: 
3 - Amex (15 digits) 
4 - Visa (13-19 digits, usually 16)  
5 - Mastercard (16 digits)  
6 - Discover (16 digits)

There are some other more rare card types like JCB and Diners which you might need to account for if your solution has to deal with those.